Connecting using fabric errors
when I use the fabric library and try to connect to the server i get the errors:
fab -f 2-do_deploy_web_static.py do_deploy:archive_path=versions/web_static_20170315003959.tgz -i ~/.ssh/key_pup

ValueError: p must be exactly 1024, 2048, or 3072 bits long
ValueError: q must be exactly 160, 224, or 256 bits long
I tried to generate another key with -b 2048, this error came up
ValueError: q must be exactly 160, 224, or 256 bits long
